# Magento reports empty rows

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

When I'm generating a report of the most viewed products there are a lot of empty rows. So from some day's I cant get any data of the most viewed products. There is reasonable traffic on the site and I know for sure that every day products are viewed.

It is a Magento 1.6 webshops. Other reports are working correctly.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Try to refresh statistics

Comment: I did refresh lifetime statistics a couple of time all ready. UPDATE: I know see that the Most Viewed Products Report is not listed in the refresh statistics page.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely coming from the DB which is used to generate this report.

Browse the table generating reports for Most Viewed Product and if you find “**store_id**” empty, edit and select the correct **store_id** for your store.

I run the following query to update all order items:

```
UPDATE table_name SET store_id=1 WHERE store_id =null;
```

This is assuming you only have 1 store and its store id = 1.

Also, take backup before running.

Comment: It is a multi store setup. Will this not cause any problems?